# How to add new column in pandas that says the occurrence of value in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do I add the column position in my pandas table, given only the first 3 columns

| roll Num | Address | WordInAddr | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Block A | Block | 1 |
| 1 | Block A | A | 2 |
| 2 | South New Jersey Street Jersey | South | 1 |
| 2 | South New Jersey Street Jersey | Jersey | 3 |
| 2 | South New Jersey Street Jersey | Street | 4 |
| 2 | South New Jersey Street Jersey | Jersey | 5 |

Comment: What's the logic for the column?

Comment: It is for NLP analysis

Comment: Not sure if the missing 2 in the second group is a typo, if not you must clarify the logic.

Comment: it is not a typo because ```new``` isnt in the column WordInAddr

Comment: Seems like you need the index `+1` of the `cumcount` *'h* occurence of each `WordInAddr` in the `Address`.

Comment: `df["Position"] = [[i for i, a in enumerate(lst, start=1) if a==w][c] for lst,w,c in zip(df["Address"].str.split(), df["WordInAddr"], df.groupby("WordInAddr").cumcount())]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy broadcasting to compute the dense matrix. Reset the lower triangle of the dense matrix and get the position (index) of the first true value.

```
def find_pos(df):
    # Extract the unique string from Address
    s = np.array(df['Address'].iloc[0].split())

    # Extract words from WordInAddr
    w = df['WordInAddr'].values[:, None]

    # Create the boolean dense matrix
    m = s == w

    # Reset the lower triangle
    m[np.tril_indices_from(m, k=-1)] = False

    # Return the position
    return pd.Series(np.argmax(m, axis=1) + 1, index=df.index)

df['Position'] = df.groupby('roll Num').apply(find_pos).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   roll Num                         Address WordInAddr  Position
0         1                         Block A      Block         1
1         1                         Block A          A         2
2         2  South New Jersey Street Jersey      South         1
3         2  South New Jersey Street Jersey     Jersey         3
4         2  South New Jersey Street Jersey     Street         4
5         2  South New Jersey Street Jersey     Jersey         5
```